# rails 6 foreign key can't be null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a migration file as the following:

```
def change
    create_table :carts do |t|
      t.string :order_number
      t.decimal :total_price
      t.bigint :user_id, null: true
      t.string :status

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

I want to allow the `user_id` to be null, but my schema file translate this migration to:

```
t.bigint "user_id", null: false
```

So in my cart.rb model even if I have

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

it doesn't work and when I try to save a cart object I get the ForeignKey can't be null error !

How I can allow null value for a foreign key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are not a declaration of current db structure, they are changes that when combined - produce it. For combined structure rails have `db/schema.rb` (or `schema.sql` for more complex scenarios)

If the column is `null: false` then it must have been changed by some later migration (or directly in db, if so - db structure may be out of sync between development and production). If you want it again to be `null: true` - add another migration that will change that. But first I'd figure out why it ended up in current state, may be there's a reason.

```
change_column :carts, :user_id, :bigint, null:true
```

Comment: Additional note: If the migration is in your current feature/topic branch, you can locally run `rails db:rollback` to revert it and then run it again with the `null: true` option

Comment: I have just one migration file where user_id is added to cart, so no other migration was changing it, however something weird happened somehow... because I was doing "rails db:reset" a few times before then when I run `rails db:migrate` it didn't show the sequence of what's happening (aka --verbose), so I tried `rails db:drop` then `rails db:create` then `rails db:migrate` and that's what solved the issue for me !! also now I can see the migrations running verbosely when I run db:migrate

Comment: I accepted your answer as you pushed me to figure out what's the issue, thanks!